# Multiple Input/Output Audio options on laptop related to Kernel 5.4.x

Tags: sound, kernel, pulseaudio, alsa

I have dual booted Ubuntu 18.04.4 with Kernel 4.15.x and Ubuntu 20.04.

On Ubuntu 18.04 (Kernel 4.15.x LTS) - sound settings show only one input and one output device which is the inbuilt speaker and headset jack. So then I connect any earphone with 3.5 mm jack, the audio auto switches to the earphone.

On Ubuntu 20.04, sound settings show multiple input/output devices. When I connect an earphone with 3.5mm jack, the audio continues to play on both speaker and earphone and I need to manually change it.

Screenshot of Ubuntu 20.04 sound settings:

[image]